# Struct containing array of structs in objective C

Tags: objective-c, struct, typedef

I have a struct for a tile (all properties are previously-defined enums)

```
typedef struct {
    ShapeType shape;
    ColorType color;
    PatternType pattern;
    IconType icon;
} TileDefinition;
```

And I want to create another struct that holds 16 tiles, for a "board". Something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    TileDefinition[16]

} BoardDefinition;
```

And then I want to be able to loop through that, like so:

```
for(int i=0;i<16;i++) {
    TileDefinition tileDef = boardDef[i];
    // Do something with tileDef
}
```

But obviously the setup for the BoardDefinition struct isn't working. How can I set that up? Where should I and shouldn't I use pointers?

Thanks

Comment: `struct { TileDefinition[16] }` looks really odd to me.  What's wrong with `struct { TileDefinition tiles[16]; }` and then using `boardDef.tiles[i]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a C question.

This bit is fine:

```
typedef struct {
    ShapeType shape;
    ColorType color;
    PatternType pattern;
    IconType icon;
} TileDefinition;
```

Here, you need to declare `BoardDefinition` as:

```
enum { BoardDefinition_NTiles = 16 }; // << declare a constant for your ease of use
typedef struct {
    TileDefinition tile[BoardDefinition_NTiles];
} BoardDefinition;
```

Then to loop through them:

```
// Given:
BoardDefinition boardDef;

for (size_t i = 0; i < BoardDefinition_NTiles; i++) {
    TileDefinition* const tile = &boardDef.tile[i]; // << get a reference to a tile
    // member access of the referenced tile:
    tile->color.red = 1;
}
```

The version you wrote creates a copy of the tile:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < BoardDefinition_NTiles; i++) {
    TileDefinition tile = boardDef.tile[i]; // << creates a copy of the tile, local to the loop body
    // member access of the copied tile:
    tile.color.red = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Make `BoardDefinition` an Objective-C object where it can be set-up in the `init` method.

Option 2: Use (Objective-)C++ and provide a constructor for `struct BoardDefinition`.

Option 3: Keep with C and provide an `initBoardDefinition(BoardDefinition *boardDef);` function.

Answer (score 0):

As trojanfoe suggest, these would be better as Objective-C objects, but if for some reason you don't wont to do that.
You probable want to declare an instance variable of type BoardDefinition in some class for example

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    BoardDefinition    definition;
}
```

Also you BoardDefinition is wrong it should be something like

```
typedef struct {
    TileDefinition      boardDef[16];

} BoardDefinition;
```

Your loop would then be something like

```
for(int i=0;i<16;i++) {
    TileDefinition tileDef = definition.boardDef[i];
    // Do something with tileDef
}
```

You don't need to use pointers put you could for the TileDefinition in the parent struct something like

```
typedef struct {
    TileDefinition    * tileDefinition;
    NSUInteger        count;
} BoardDefinition;
```

This way you can have a variable number of TileDefinition. In this case you would have to malloc the tileDefinition soemthing like the following for the class init method.

```
- (id)init
{
    if( (self = [super init]) != nil )
    {
        definition.count = 16;
        definition.tileDefinition = malloc( definition.count * sizeof(*definition.tileDefinition);
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: "these would be better as Objective-C objects" -- *Why?*

Comment: Well, don't take that question seriously -- just my way of pointing out that there's no evident reason/benefit in converting the type to ObjC, given the information/problem in the OP.

Comment: I'm going to send these via Game Center to other players and want to keep them as lightweight as possible